# T-SQL WHERE NOT EXISTS - inconsistent results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

I have a problem where some orders with od.[Bin Code] = 'HISS' are being selected even though this query containing NOT EXISTS works most of the time. Could someone explain how those orders are being selected sometimes only? And how we can fix it?

```
SELECT *
FROM   [NAV2009].[dbo].[company\$sales line] AS line 
       JOIN [NAV2009].[dbo].[company\$sales header] AS Header 
         ON line.[document no_] = Header.no_ 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   [NAV2009].[dbo].[company\$sales line] od 
                   WHERE  line.[document no_] = od.[document no_] 
                          AND od.[bin code] = 'HISS') 
       AND Header.[website code] = 'DEFAULT' 
       AND [general comments] <> 'Picking'
```

Comment: Your query look ok to me. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: We can't validate your query without the underlying data, who knows if it's working as desired or not? Only you!

Comment: Usually this is due to inconsistent data, blanks most often, sometimes control characters or just upper/lower case issues (e.g. `'HIS'` ≠ `'HIS '` ≠ `' HIS'` ≠ `'his'`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: At least trailing blanks will not cause this problem in SQL Server (trailing spaces are ignored according to Standard SQL)

Comment: you need to find an example that 'should' have been selected, but wasn't, then find out which clause in the SELECT was false- or did the JOIN fail?  I wouldn't just make changes to see if it will 'go away'

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that not all `'HISS'`s are the same.  Perhaps spaces are the culprit.  You can try queries such as:

```
select od.[Bin Code]
from [NAV2009].[dbo].[company\$sales line] od 
where od.[Bin Code] like '%H%I%S%S%' and
      od.[Bin Code] <> 'HISS';
```

Once you understand the culprit, you can think of how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, especially without sample data and that we can see OP's screen, but this can be rewritten without the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as

```
FROM [NAV2009].[dbo].[Company\$Sales Line] AS line
INNER JOIN [NAV2009].[dbo].[company\$Sales Header] AS Header 
        ON  line.[Document No_] = Header.No_
    --to exclude rows where od.[Bin Code] <> 'HISS' then include in JOIN
        AND od.[Bin Code] <> 'HISS'
WHERE Header.[Website Code] <> 'DEFAULT'
AND [General Comments] = 'Picking'
```

Comment: this cant not. this would only remove the document with `code <> hiss` he want remove all document if any is `<> hiss`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the varbinary you will likely see a difference

```
SELECT 'HISS', CAST('HISS' AS VARBINARY(4))
```